# iCanHaz.js not loading a template when the page is loaded

Tags: jquery, icanhaz.js

I want to load a template once my index page is loaded. My index pages contains:

```
<script src="site/introduction.html" type="text/html"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/lib/ICanHaz.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app/main2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and main2.js contains:

```
$(function() {
   var introduction_html = ich.introduction();
   $('#pm').html(introduction_html.filter('#introduction'));
});
```

The introduction template is not found! Even if I use ich.grabTemplates() before calling it, it does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

introduction.html contains:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
P.submit {text-align: left}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="introduction">

<p>The tool can now guide you, step by step, through this procedure, beginning when you click on the "start" button below.</p>

<form action="">
<p class="submit"><input  type="submit" value="Start" /></p>
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ThomasClayson, you mean **I CAN HAZ CONSOLES OUTPUT ?**

Comment: I get the error

    Object #<ICanHaz> has no method 'introduction'

Comment: Can you post the content of introduction.html?

Comment: The ajax callback that grab the template is called after the call ich.introduction... How can I synchronize these things?

Comment: Should the template be defined like this: <script id="introduction" type="text/html">content</script> ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that remote templates are grab by ICanHaz asynchronously and they are not available at the time I want to use them to render the page.

I found two different solutions:

1) define the templates directly in the page with a script tag. This is a bit ugly to my taste.

2) make the ICanHaz call synchronous. If you have few templates this is a reasonable trade-off. I changed this piece of code from:

```
        $.ajax({url: script.prop('src'), dataType: 'text',
```

to

```
        $.ajax({async: false, url: script.prop('src'), dataType: 'text',
```

This does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `ich.refresh()` to load the templates which are loaded with ajax